# JS - Regex replacing happens multiple times in one call, how do I get it to run once?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've got a string

```
Yes (+1500)
```

and I want to replace the `(+ $1500)` with `(+ $1700)` (or `- $1700`, or `0`, or any number really)

So I'm testing with this regex: `/\(\+(.+?)\)|\(\-(.+?)\)/`

```
var string = 'Yes (+ $1500)';
string.replace(/\(\+(.+?)\)|\(\-(.+?)\)/, '(+ $1700)');

// returns "Yes (+  $1500700)"
```

And if I try it with other numbers it returns similar values

```
var string = 'Yes (+ $1500)';
string.replace(/\(\+(.+?)\)|\(\-(.+?)\)/, '(+ $1700)');

// returns "Yes (+  $1500700)"
// desired result: "Yes (+ $1700)"

var string = 'Yes (+ $1500)';
string.replace(/\(\+(.+?)\)|\(\-(.+?)\)/, '(- $1700)');

// returns "Yes (-  $1500700)"
// desired result: "Yes (- $1700)"

var string = 'Yes (+ $1500)';
string.replace(/\(\+(.+?)\)|\(\-(.+?)\)/, '(- $12345)');

// returns "Yes (-  $15002345)"
// desired result: "Yes (- $12345)"
```

I think this is because the regex command `/\(\+(.+?)\)|\(\-(.+?)\)/` returns multiple matches from the string `Yes (+ $1500)`:

```
var string = 'yes (+ $1500)';
/\(\+(.+?)\)|\(\-(.+?)\)/.exec(string);

// returns: 
//     ["(+ $1500)", " $1500", undefined]
```

So I think there's something weird where .replace is seeing 2 or more matches to the regex command, and tries to replace both of them.

Does `.replace()` replace multiple matches or just the one?

---

Here's a regex example of my regex command: https://regex101.com/r/qH0sR1/1

Comment: You need to double `$` in the replacement string, then you'll get `Yes (+ $1700)`

Comment: Ugh. So freaking simple. Thanks Wiktor!

Answer (score 0):

You need to double `$` in the replacement string and you can just use a `[-+]` character class to match either `-` or `+`:

```js
var string = 'Yes (+ $1500)';
document.body.innerHTML = string.replace(/\(([+-])[^)]*\)/, '($1 $$1700)');
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/yA5jK4/1). The `$` must be doubled since it should escape the `$` that denotes a backreference.

- `\(` - matches a `(`
- `([+-])` - matches and captures into Group 1 `+` or `-`
- `[^)]*` - matches 0+ characters other than `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`

The pattern can be further improved, like `/\(([+-])\s*\$\d+\)/` or `/\(([+-])\s*\$?\d+\)/`. Add `/g` modifier if you need to make multiple replacements.